# Issue while mapping blankspaces

Tags: oracle, biztalk

I am not sure if its the BizTalk error, thought I will check. I am trying to insert blank spaces in to the Oracle Table through the scripting functions

```
public string GetMXValue()
 {
   return "                                ";
 }
```

So it returns 32 blank spaces to insert in to a field in Oracle Table. But we get an error

Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.TargetSystemException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEVLAW"."GLTRANSREL"."MX_VALUE_02")

I am doing the right way to insert the blankspaces? I even tried using the String functiods and passed 32 blankspaces. Are black spaces treated as NULL in Oracle?

The field exists in the table
[image]

Comment: _"Are black spaces treated as NULL in Oracle?"_ No. They are not. Empty strings are treated as NULL, but spaces are spaces. So, there is something before Oracle.

Comment: the column MX_VALUE_02 is the same as the column you try to insert?

Comment: @FlorinGhita Yes the column exists in Oracle Table

Comment: sure it exists(the error tells that). I asked if it is the same as the column you try to update/insert.

Comment: Yes it is just the same. I have inserted the pic of the column

Comment: Check the XML payload that is going to Oracle in the BizTalk Administration Console.  BizTalk has a habit of removing trailing whitespace.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/915612a5-cd87-4498-afcc-141ff05de02b/biztalk-and-whitespace-preservation?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: I checked those by Test Map and the output XML have those blank spaces.

Comment: In addition to @Dijkgraaf's comment, see if adding an `xml:space='preserve'` attribute to the element helps any.